# Need to identify electronic part of an unit of my 1988 Chrysler leBaron. Think it's a varistor but I am not familiar with the code on it

Tags: varistor

Looking for a replacement part of this varistor.
[image]

Comment: What diameter is it? What lead pitch is it? What thickness is it?

Answer (score 1):

The company TDK lists metal oxide varistors in the 722 series, designed for high temperature applications in automotive environment. The other four digits "2598" may be part of an ordering code, but don't match any current listings I can see [here](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/protection/voltage/lead-disk-varistor/data_sheet/70/db/var/siov_snf_automotive.pdf).

While there's a chance the varistor failed independently, it's more likely a secondary effect from some other failure that caused a voltage spike.  For example, a "load dump" occurs when a car battery is accidentally disconnected from the alternator while it's still turning.

You might get more help from the automotive section on StackExchange.